# Android Studio, to create Settings in app, should I use Scrollview or ListView?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, settings

Just an example of Settings i'm referring to:

[image]

For My app, one of the tab bars will be Settings. In settings I'll include buttons for name, mobile number, username, password, privacy policy, Terms of Service. To create this for settings, is it best to create it using a ScrollView or a ListView? Why one is better than the other for Settings?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

or (even better) this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

Here is the guide:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

*Don't reinvent the wheel.*